# Acceder a atributos desde un ArrayList de objetos C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, diseño-de-clases

Tengo que crear un menú donde una de sus opciones establece el valor del atributo de un objeto, cuya clase ya tiene instanciados guardadas en un `ArrayList`.

La pregunta es: ¿cómo accedo a ese atributo ?

```
class Producto
{
    public string tipo;
    public double precio;
    public Producto() {}
}
```

Así se van añadiendo objetos a la lista:

```
Console.Write("¿Cuantos productos quiere dar de alta? ");
int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("");

for (int o = 1; o <= i; o++)
{
    Producto a = new Producto();
    lista.Add(a);
}
```

Lo que tengo que hacer es: a ciertos productos añadirles una variable "descuento" que, luego, quiero añadir al array.

Comment: Me late que estás iniciando en la programación, revisa esto: https://github.com/fredyfx/Curso-Programando-En-One/blob/master/ProgramandoEnOne/Program.cs te será de utilidad

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. En tu clase `Producto` no hay ninguna propiedad descuento. Además, estás dando de alta productos vacíos, sin ninguna propiedad con valor. Trata de [edit] tu pregunta para aclarar estos puntos, y tambien que problema tienes para acceder a las propiedades.

Comment: Necesitas utilizar herencia, es decir , crear una clase que herede de `Producto`, para que haya objetos que sean especializaciones de productos, y que tengan un atributo más (en este caso descuento).

Comment: Cuando dices "atributo", ¿Te refieres a "propiedad"?